# How to make the result in date format using datediff btween 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make the result for `datediff`(interval result) in date format.

I have a view that had columns with numbers, and the other view contains the today date value.

I want to make a date diff between these 2 values, and get the results as a date too.
For example: result 10 for `2018/12/31` and `2018/12/21`.

The date format is: `YYYY,MM,DD`

[image]

Comment: Query:

SELECT        dbo.View_Count_Number_of_SRs_Per_Day_Step1.F1, dbo.View_Today_Date_for_Mail_Notification.Date2, DATEDIFF(month, dbo.View_Count_Number_of_SRs_Per_Day_Step1.F1, 
                         dbo.View_Today_Date_for_Mail_Notification.Date2) AS F3
FROM            dbo.View_Count_Number_of_SRs_Per_Day_Step1 CROSS JOIN
                         dbo.View_Today_Date_for_Mail_Notification

Comment: 1) this does not look like mysql. The code seems to be ms sql. 2) what do you mean by getting the difference between two dates as a date? You could say that you want to add or subtract certain number of days / weeks/ months / years from the current date and get the result as date.

Comment: please see the image

Comment: What is the datatype of the column that stores today’s date ? Date, datetime or varchar ?

Comment: @FatinRIMAWI Hi, You try to add F1 month to the date (date2) ? It's what your're looking ?

I think you have to use DATEADD and no DATEDIFF but i didn't see what results your're expected.

Comment: The result of `DateDiff` is a number, not a date. Perhaps you are looking for `DateAdd`?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you want to subtract x days from a given date.
Use the [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
SELECT 10 F1, '2018-12-31' Date2, DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())F3
```

> Notice: In order to subtract using the DATEADD function we use a negative value (-10)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add number of date to given date then you can use the below query.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DD, 10, '2018-12-21'), 23) AS DateAfterAdd;

--or

SELECT Cast(CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DD, 10, '2018-12-21'), 23) as Date) AS DateAfterAdd;
```

The output is as shown below

```
DateAfterAdd
2018-12-31
```

Comment: Here you can replace '2018-12-21' to actual column name.